# suppress rjava error output in console

Tags: java, r, rstudio, rjava

How can I suppress the `rJava` output to the console in the following example?

```
library(rJava)
TC <- J("edu.cens.spatial.RTileController")
         dummy <- capture.output(suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(
res <- TC$getInstance(type="osm-bw")$getTileValues(4389,2691,13)
         )))
```

Despite `capture.output`, I still get the following in the console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cens.spatial.RTileController.getTileValues(RTileController.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
```

**Edit**: In pure R Console (without Rstudio), I get no messages (but I have to call `library("OpenStreetMap")` first). So this might be an Rstudio issue after all ... The question is now: **how can I suppres Java output to the R console in Rstudio?** Is it possible to do this when calling `osmtile` as outlined below?

PS1: It works for `osm` instead of `osm-bw`.
PS2: I came across this via

```
tile <- OpenStreetMap::osmtile(x=4389,y=2691,zoom=13,type="osm-bw")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, something like this works - NullPointer message is suppressed:

```
> s <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="V", method="nullcall")
Error in .jcall(obj, returnSig = "V", method = "nullcall") :
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception
> suppressMessages(s <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="V", method="nullcall"))
```

To reproduce this code do following:

1. Create file (from within R)

   ```
   dir.create("utils")
   dir.create("target")
   cat('package utils;

   public class RUsingStringArray {
     public void nullcall() throws NullPointerException {
       throw new NullPointerException("Exception");
     }
     public static void main(String [] arg) {
       RUsingStringArray obj = new RUsingStringArray();
       obj.nullcall();
     }
   }', file="utils/RUsingStringArray.java")
   ```
2. Compile java code (in cmd / terminal, last line won't work on windows)

   ```
   javac -d target utils/*.java
   java -cp target utils/RUsingStringArray
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception
     at utils.RUsingStringArray.nullcall(RUsingStringArray.java:19)
     at utils.RUsingStringArray.main(RUsingStringArray.java:24)
   export CLASSPATH=`pwd`/target
   ```
3. Inside R

   ```
   library(rJava)
   .jinit("C:/path_to_folder/target") # leave empty if CLASSPATH was set
   obj <- .jnew("utils.RUsingStringArray")
                    s <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="V", method="nullcall")
   suppressMessages(s <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="V", method="nullcall"))

   Error in .jcall(obj, returnSig = "V", method = "nullcall") :
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception
   ```

Comment: With this, I get an error every second time I run it, regardless of whether there is `suppressMessages` or not...

Comment: No problem. Go ahead.